# Adding multiple DynamoDB set items through terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

**terraform version: 0.12.20**

I wanted to add multiple items with set datatype in terraform, I went through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320641/adding-multiple-dynamodb-items-through-terraform) where an example has shown how to add simple data type as String but it fails to add with Set

Below is the code that I am testing

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "items" {
  hash_key   = "key"
  table_name = "test"
  for_each = {
    "72" = {
      test = ["114717","2"],
      test1 = []
    },
    "25" = {
      test = ["114717"],
      test1 = []
    }
  }
  item = <<EOF
{
  "key": {"S": "${each.key}"},
  "test": {"SS": "${each.value.test}"},
  "test1": {"SS": "${each.value.test1}"}
}
EOF
}
```

However, it fails with `Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.`

I tried something like

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "items" {
  hash_key   = "key"
  table_name = "test"
  for_each = {
    "72" = {
      test = "114717,2",
      test1 = ""
    },
    "25" = {
      test = "114717",
      test1 = ""
    }
  }
  item = <<EOF
{
  "key": {"S": "${each.key}"},
  "test": {"SS": ["${each.value.test}"]},
  "test1": {"SS": ["${each.value.test1}"]}
}
EOF
}
```

This fails to differentiate `"114717,2"` as two different items

In the second example, I have even tried the below section too

```
{
  "key": {"S": "${each.key}"},
  "test": {"SS": "${split(",",each.value.test)}"},
  "test1": {"SS": "${split(",",each.value.test1)}"}
}
```

This also fails with `Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.`

I am expecting to be able to split the values into array `["114717","2"]`. This will help me to store the values as Set in DynamoDB

Comment: What does it mean "This fails to differentiate "114717,2" as two different items"? What is the actual outcome, why it is wrong, and what should be the expected result?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my question for a better understanding

Comment: What are `whiteListedCustomers` and `blackListedCustomers`?. There are no such variables defined in your code.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, I did code obfuscation & missed removing those, updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `item` should be **valid json**. To achieve that, you can use [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html):

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "items" {
  hash_key   = "key"
  table_name = "GameScores"
  for_each = {
    "72" = {
      test = ["114717","2"],
      test1 = []
    },
    "25" = {
      test = ["114717"],
      test1 = []
    }
  }
  item = <<EOF
{
  "key": {"S": "${each.key}"},
  "test": {"SS": ${jsonencode(each.value.test)}},
  "test1": {"SS": ${length(each.value.test1) > 0 ? jsonencode(each.value.test1) : jsonencode([""])}}
}
EOF
}
```

Also `SS` **can't be empty**, so you have to account for that. Thus you have to check for that and use `[""]` array. Or you have to re-consider what to do if your `test1` is `[]`.

Comment: I have tried this as well, terraform plan fails due to the constraint of SS as array, will post exact error in bit

Comment: @Sach The code works. I run it and verified it.